# Did I incorrectly implement Prepared Statements on Java for my transaction_login method? I'm not sure when to have SQLExceptions

Tags: java, mysql, azure, hash, prepared-statement

UPDATE 1:30 PM MAY 12: I edited my code a good deal, but the test cases still don't run. I'm not sure where to start since the test cases are simple to begin with. It would just be helpful to understand where it might be going wrong.

login takes in a username and password, and checks that the user exists in the database and that the password matches. To compute the hash, adapt the above code.
Within a single session (that is, a single instance of your program), only one user should be logged in. A good practice is for every test case to begin with a login request. Make sure you log the User out when the prograsm terminates. To keep things simple, you can track the login status of a User  using a local variable in your program. You should not need to track a user's login status inside the database.
If a second login attempt is made, please return "User already logged in".

```
  public String transaction_login(String username, String password) {
    if (LOGGED_IN == 0) {
      try {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, HASH_STRENGTH, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = null;
        byte[] hash = null;
        try {
          factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
          hash = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
          throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        /* RUNNING SQL QUERY*/
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(USER_ACCESS);
        while (rs.next()) {
          String result_username = rs.getString("username");
          byte[] result_hash = rs.getByte("hashVal");
          if (result_username.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && Arrays.equals(result_hash, hash)) {
              LOGGED_IN++;
              return "Logged in as " + username + "\n";
          }
        }
        rs.close();
        return "Login failed\n";
      } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        se.getErrorCode();
      } finally {
        checkDanglingTransaction();
      }
    } else {
      return "User already logged in\n";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, you do not seem to use `PreparedStatement` at all, you have not provided  `USER_ACCESS` query, and you compare strings with `==` operator instead of `.equals` which is the most incorrect.

Comment: Hi sorry, USER_ACCESS was implemented as a final static variable, which ended up being the following:

private static final String USER_ACCESS = "SELECT * FROM Users";

I also changed the byte comparison if statement by comparing with .equals by using toString on my password hash by doing the following:

result_password.toString().equals(hash.toString())

I also tried using Statement here since it is a general purpose query that I want the result set from.

Answer (score 0):

Your part with the statement needs to be fixed to resolve multiple issues:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(USER_ACCESS); // SELECT * FROM User
while (rs.next()) {
    String result_username = rs.getString("username");
    byte[] result_password = rs.getBytes("password"); // not single byte
    if (result_username.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && Arrays.equals(result_password, hash)) {
        LOGGED_IN++;  
        return "Logged in as " + username + "\n";
    } // do not return here, check for other users!
}
rs.close();
return "Login failed\n";
```